# What is the "create dump file" feature in Task Manager?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, dump

Recently I came to find about a feature (option) by right clicking on process in Task Manager on Windows 10:

[image]

I want to know what does the feature stand for and what can I do with it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a debugging tool for programmers.

It takes a snapshot of all the stuff that that program has stored in RAM and writes it to a file on disk. Programmers can then pore through that information to try to understand what went wrong.

Memory dumps (core dumps) are mostly useless unless you're a programmer with access to the source code of the program whose memory you dumped to disk.

Comment: Are memory dump and core dump same?

Comment: where is the file stored on windows 10 ?

Comment: Nevermind you have to wait until the process of file creation is finished. The process that i wanted to dump crashed before it could finish...

Comment: @firephil You still have an option even when it is crashing.  Use "WinDbg" (install with the Windows Development SDK) and use "WinDbg -I" to set it up as what's called the default "post-mortem" debugger.  This means as your process is crashing, it will attach "WinDbg" to it.  When WinDbg is attached, it is open and you can issue a command to grab a memory dump from it, so you can debug the crashing process.